# Vectors in Javascript that need to pass a Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, vector, jasmine

Ive only started coding recently and am still trying to figure out how everything works, my teacher has given me this work and taught us how to make the constructor but nothing about the other stuff. I was wondering if someone could help me complete the Add function so it passes the tests and then hopefully from there I can deduce the other functions on my own, thanks :).

This is the specification
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcYP1.png)

This is the current code state

```js
  constructor(pX, pY, pZ) {
    this.setX(pX);
    this.setY(pY);
    this.setZ(pZ);
  }
  getX() {
    return this.mX;
  }
  setX(pX) {
    this.mX = pX;
  }
  getY() {
    return this.mY;
  }
  setY(pY) {
    this.mY = pY;
  }
  getZ() {
    return this.mZ;
  }
  setZ(pZ) {
    this.mZ = pZ;
  }

  add(vec) {
    var mX, mY, pX, pY, x, y;

    mX = this.getX();
    mY = this.getY();
    pX = vec.x;
    pY = vec.y;
    x = mX + pX;
    y = mY + pY;

    return new Vector(x, y);
  }
```

and this is the jasmine test I have to pass.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0B1l.png)

if someone can tell me how to code the add function hopefully I could do the rest on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have exactly same specification as you. For your add method, here is what I wrote.

```
add(pVector) {
    return new Vector(this.getX() + pVector.getX(), this.getY() + pVector.getY(), this.getZ() + pVector.getZ())
}
```

You can use variables if you wish to be able to manually check the variables, however for me I simply left them out for convenience. You can probably get yours to work if you simply change the "vec.x" and vec.y" to "vec.getX()" and "vec.getY()". Although I'm not so familiar with this language myself. So just copied my working current method. But the reason you after write getX() is because you have methods already from the code David gave to us which get and set the X value of the vector. So your simply calling to the Vector vec, and then you are getting the X value "getX()".

Prob a poor explanation, but feel free to add me on disc if you need more, im too working through this atm SEIORI#5498

You can pretty much follow this formula for all the methods nearly, just changing operator based on the method.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful, it may seem rude to ask but Im also struggling on the matrix getElement and constructor bit for the jasmine test. Would you possibly be able to give me a hint on how to get started on it?